# RTMP stream in IE doesn't in Safari, Firefox?bu

Tags: flash, apache-flex, internet-explorer, video, rtmp

I've got a flex app streaming video.
Up until last week it worked fine consuming the video from our CDN. Now however, the live streams will work correctly in only certain browsers.

The NetStream object will connect to and start playing the stream, but just is in a constant bufferring state. No video is ever displayed.

Some people have it only working in FF but not Chrome, Safari or IE. For me it only streams correctly in IE!!

Has anyone experienced something like this before? I'm using identical code, that all used to work brilliantly.

Any help is really appreciated!

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced it and it gave me headaches !!!
I finally found there was a bug since version 11.1.102.62 in Flash player.
You will find the bug related [here in the bugbase platform of Adobe](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3117684).

And for my users, I propose a temporary [workaround explained here](http://www.bestkicker.com/forum/13-annonces-officielles/30403-incompatibilite-firefox-adobe-flash-player-111-streaming-video-rtmp.html#1), and put the necessary files on my website.
I hope you know a little bit french.

Does it help ?

Comment: Thanks, I found that same bug after a while.

Comment: For your information, I tested the beta version 11.3 of Adobe Flash Player and it finally correct the bug :)